# Error while booting Unity on Chromebook

Tags: unity, chromebook

After following a guide on how to set up Ubuntu it worked fine. I shut down my computer and restarted. Afterwards, I tried booting it again from the Chromebook terminal, it would not start and I would receive this error:
http://pastebin.com/7ahqj6Ka

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please also provide the log file at: `/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log`

Answer (score 0):

I know I have the exact same problem!!! I think you have to delete and re-download ubuntu entirely. Cause what caused it for me was that I downloaded Steam on ubuntu and used up almost the entire memory, then i got the error screen and i checked my files and it said "some files may have been temporarily or permanently deleted to conserve space" or somehting like that. So I deleted Steam From Chrome to make space but i still got the error, i even entered the chroot to delete steam and it still didnt work which means i did delete steam but I still Have the error. So I assume for both of us it Permanently disabled/deleted the crouton file. So Unless I find a soulution im gonna delete and re-download ubuntu. you should too.